# Why do tokamaks need to operate in pulsed mode?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, fusion

> The plasma current is normally induced by a transformer coil in the plasma. A Tokamak therefore does not operate continuously, but in pulsed mode like the transformer.

*https://www.ipp.mpg.de/1766212/tokamak*

I do understand that induction only occurs when the magnetic flux changes over time, however after hitting the current limit in the transformer the current could be decreased at the same rate it was increased at which should create the same current.
This would also reverse the current induced into the plasma, however the magnetic field created by this current is only meant to counteract the drift of the plasma towards the torus wall, isn't it?

Comment: IMO what you say makes sense, and the book text is unclear. I would say it is pulsed because if it ran continuously, the shell would get too hot from radiation and/or stray plasma particles.

Comment: One would need a current supply capable of providing the current continuously, which is much harder than a pulsed supply. And don’t forget the magnetization curve you need to deal with.

Comment: @Jon Custer So they use supercapacitors? Also what do you mean with 'dealing with the magnetization curve'?

Comment: @Trigus - the magnetic hysterisis curve for the transformer core material - an ac transformer automatically reverses the curve, a pulsed one has a separate reset circuit.

Comment: And regular caps work just fine.

Comment: Why doesn't a stellerator have to operate in pulsed mode, then? I don't think they are that much more power efficient. If they were, research surely wouldn't be focused on tokamaks.